# From convergence pointwise to convergence of the supremum for semicontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ a compact set, and $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $f$ upper semicontinuous functions over $K$ (taking hence values in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$) such that for all $x\in K$, the sequence $\big(f_n(x)\big)$ is decreasing, and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$.

**Question:** Do $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sup_K(f_n)=\sup_K(f)$?